# Connection Issue When Dynamically Publishing to a Tridion Broker Database with an Instance Name (JDBC)?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

The commit phase always fails with this error:

```
Committing Deployment Failed
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0515104-66560,
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection,
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-515104-66560, 
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection,
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
```

This is the configuration that works in databases with default instances (DEV/UAT):

```xml
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="brokerdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="ourServerName" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="xxxxxxxxpassxx" />
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>
```

However, for our production, using a named instance is inevitable. So we tried this configuration to pass the instance's name but to no avail; we still get the error.

```xml
<Storage Type="persistence" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" 
    Id="brokerdb"
    Url="jdbc:sqlserver://ourServerName/Tridion_Broker;instanceName=THE_INSTANCE_NAME;domain=DOMAIN_NAME" 
    Username="TridionBrokerUser" 
    Password="xxxxxxxxpassxx" 
    Driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
</Storage>
```

Is there anything wrong with the connection string? Or is there a way to pass the instance name using the first pattern; say `<Property Name="instanceName" Value="THE_INSTANCE_NAME" />` for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Nikoli and Gertjan's [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx) made me realize that the instance name is not required. **An alternative is to specify the port to which the instance is running on.**

This [article](http://dbamohsin.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/quickest-way-to-find-a-sql-server-instance-port-number/) showed me how to know which port is being used for the instance.

This configuration worked:

```xml
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="brokerdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
        <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
        <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
            <Property Name="serverName" Value="ourServerName" />
            <Property Name="portNumber" Value="43333" />
            <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
            <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
            <Property Name="password" Value="xxxxxxxxpassxx" />
        </DataSource>
    </Storage>
```

I also tried the connection string approach and it worked, too:

```xml
<Storage Type="persistence" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" 
    dialect="MSSQL" 
    Id="brokerdb" 
    Url="jdbc:sqlserver://ourServerName:43333;databaseName=Tridion_Broker;" 
    Username="TridionBrokerUser" Password="xxxxxxxxpassxx" 
    Driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
    <Pool Type="jdbc2" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
</Storage>
```

Comment: If any of the below responses answered your question, could you please  accept that as an answer so it will be helpful for other community members.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```xml
<Property Name="serverName" Value="ourServerName\ourInstanceName" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original syntax of specifying the URL is correct, however, upon checking the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I can't seem to find a valid property called "domain". This may be your culprit. Try specifying the domain in the username using a '\'.

Comment: You're right, domain is not needed in our case. It is integral to the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to this msdn article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

you should configure it like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

Comment: also you seem to be missing the dialect="MSSQL" attribute on the Storage element

Answer (score 1):

You should combine both server name and instance name.

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="brokerdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="ourServerName\\THE_INSTANCE_NAME" />
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
        <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
        <Property Name="password" Value="xxxxxxxxpassxx" />
    </DataSource>
</Storage>​
```

Another way, I have changed URL little bit for this old representation

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="brokerdb" Url="jdbc:sqlserver://ourServerName;instanceName=THE_INSTANCE_NAME;databaseName=Tridion_Broker;integratedSecurity=true;" Username="TridionBrokerUser" Password="xxxxxxxxpassxx"    Driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
</Storage>
```

Try these URL for the above Old representation:-

1. `jdbc:sqlserver://ourServerName\\THE_INSTANCE_NAME;databaseName=Tridion_Broker;integratedSecurity=true;`
2. `jdbc:sqlserver://ourServerName\THE_INSTANCE_NAME;databaseName=Tridion_Broker;integratedSecurity=true;`
3. `jdbc:sqlserver://ourServerName;instanceName=THE_INSTANCE_NAME;databaseName=Tridion_Broker;integratedSecurity=true;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`
4. `jdbc:sqlserver://ourServerName/Tridion_Broker;instanceName=THE_INSTANCE_NAME;domain=DOMAIN_NAME;`

For your references:-

1. **[Building the Connection URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**
2. **[Setting the Connection Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

Comment: The `<Property Name="serverName" Value="ourServerName\\THE_INSTANCE_NAME" />` didn't work. This is the same as Puntero's answer. As for the "connection string" approach, #2 worked without the `integratedSecurity` parameter.